# How the heck do I get these json variables? - PHP Notice: Trying to get property 'title' of non-object

Tags: php, json

I'm having some trouble retrieving the "title" and "url" fields from this JSON output.  I have done this in the past, but never from such a complex hierarchy.  Here is what I have tried.

Code block that matters:

```
$response_raw = curl_exec( $ch );
$response = json_decode( $response_raw );
curl_close( $ch );

print_r ($response);

echo $response->data->title;  // NOT CORRECT
echo $response->data->url;  // NOT CORRECT
```

Giant JSON block:

```
(
    [kind] => Listing
    [data] => stdClass Object
        (
            [modhash] => 
            [dist] => 11
            [children] => Array
                (
                    [0] => stdClass Object
                        (
                            [kind] => t3
                            [data] => stdClass Object
                                (
                                    [approved_at_utc] => 
                                    [subreddit] => freebies
                                    [selftext] => 
                                    [author_fullname] => t2_100cy6
                                    [saved] => 
                                    [mod_reason_title] => 
                                    [gilded] => 0
                                    [clicked] => 
                                    [title] => Send a Halloween card to a child at Children's Hospital LA
                                    [link_flair_richtext] => Array
                                        (
                                        )

                                    [subreddit_name_prefixed] => r/freebies
                                    [hidden] => 
                                    [pwls] => 6
                                    [link_flair_css_class] => 
                                    [downs] => 0
                                    [parent_whitelist_status] => all_ads
                                    [hide_score] => 
                                    [name] => t3_9sjqk2
                                    [quarantine] => 
                                    [link_flair_text_color] => dark
                                    [author_flair_background_color] => 
                                    [subreddit_type] => public
                                    [ups] => 456
                                    [domain] => secure1.chla.org
                                    [media_embed] => stdClass Object
                                        (
                                        )

                                    [author_flair_template_id] => 
                                    [is_original_content] => 
                                    [user_reports] => Array
                                        (
                                        )

                                    [secure_media] => 
                                    [is_reddit_media_domain] => 
                                    [is_meta] => 
                                    [category] => 
                                    [secure_media_embed] => stdClass Object
                                        (
                                        )

                                    [link_flair_text] => 
                                    [can_mod_post] => 
                                    [score] => 456
                                    [approved_by] => 
                                    [thumbnail] => 
                                    [edited] => 
                                    [author_flair_css_class] => 
                                    [author_flair_richtext] => Array
                                        (
                                        )

                                    [gildings] => stdClass Object
                                        (
                                            [gid_1] => 0
                                            [gid_2] => 0
                                            [gid_3] => 0
                                        )

                                    [content_categories] => 
                                    [is_self] => 
                                    [mod_note] => 
                                    [created] => 1540894163
                                    [link_flair_type] => text
                                    [wls] => 6
                                    [banned_by] => 
                                    [author_flair_type] => text
                                    [contest_mode] => 
                                    [selftext_html] => 
                                    [likes] => 
                                    [suggested_sort] => confidence
                                    [banned_at_utc] => 
                                    [view_count] => 
                                    [archived] => 
                                    [no_follow] => 
                                    [is_crosspostable] => 1
                                    [pinned] => 
                                    [over_18] => 
                                    [media_only] => 
                                    [link_flair_template_id] => 
                                    [can_gild] => 1
                                    [spoiler] => 
                                    [locked] => 
                                    [author_flair_text] => 
                                    [visited] => 
                                    [num_reports] => 
                                    [distinguished] => 
                                    [subreddit_id] => t5_2qi1v
                                    [mod_reason_by] => 
                                    [removal_reason] => 
                                    [link_flair_background_color] => 
                                    [id] => 9sjqk2
                                    [is_robot_indexable] => 1
                                    [report_reasons] => 
                                    [author] => kushmaster10
                                    [num_crossposts] => 0
                                    [num_comments] => 45
                                    [send_replies] => 1
                                    [mod_reports] => Array
                                        (
                                        )

                                    [author_patreon_flair] => 
                                    [author_flair_text_color] => 
                                    [permalink] => /r/freebies/comments/9sjqk2/send_a_halloween_card_to_a_child_at_childrens/
                                    [whitelist_status] => all_ads
                                    [stickied] => 
                                    [url] => https://secure1.chla.org/site/SPageNavigator/Halloween2018.html;jsessionid=00000000.app205b?utm_source=em3&amp;utm_medium=email&amp;utm_campaign=hall18&amp;s_src=hall18em3&amp;NONCE_TOKEN=8BF78C172D2DE329607E0BE46623F05C
                                    [subreddit_subscribers] => 609487
                                    [created_utc] => 1540865363
                                    [media] => 
                                    [is_video] => 
                                )

                        )
```

Any help on retrieving these 2 variables is much appreciated.

Comment: After `$response->data` the only valid selections are `->modhash`, `->dist`, or `->children`. If you want the title for the first child, then do `$response->data->children[0]->data->title`

Comment: You've learned to pretty print the json so you can actually see the hiarchy right there. To get the URL you just start at the $response and then drill down. $response->data->children[0]->data->url. BUT! You probably get more children so you should iterate over $reponse->data->children and then get $child->data->url for each "row"

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How do I extract data from JSON with PHP?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29308898/how-do-i-extract-data-from-json-with-php)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your current code is attempting to retrieve those variable from the first `data` object, but you need to retrieve them from the `data` object that is nested further down. Your calls should look something like this:

```
echo $response->data->children[0]->data->title;
echo $response->data->children[0]->data->url;
```

As others have stated, it is likely that you will have a scenario where more than one "child" is included in the "children" array. To iterate through multiple children, you could use something like this:

```
foreach($response->data->children as $child){
    $childTitle = $child->data->title;
    $childURL = $child->data->url;
    //do something with these values
};
```

Comment: Yes!, you are correct.  I also needed to loop through the results.  I tried this, and it worked perfectly.  Thank you so much for your help.